# How to make the layout_weight work the same for API18-19 as for the other API levels?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout-weight

Here is what I want to get as a result, and I am getting for **API <=17** and **API >=20**:
[image: Correct result on API25]

However for the **API 18-19** the FrameViews's height doesn't respect the `layout_weight` values:

[image]

The issue might be related with the fact, that to make the `panelLayout` height really `match_parent`, I need to add the `layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

This is the complete layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrappingScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/longView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/longView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/longView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/longView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:padding="5dp"
                >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:padding="5dp"
                >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Don't you have an idea, how to make Android lay out these views the same on every API level from 17 up? Consider size of the `longView` dynamic.

Comment: Update RelativeLayout's height to match_parent.

Comment: @PavneetSingh I found something else while looking more in attached screenshots. View is taking full height as per screen size. Issues seems to be with FrameLayout's weight property.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837978/frame-layout-not-adjusting-layout-weight

Comment: You can join me here - https://join.skype.com/CP1OA5QWz58c

Answer (score 1):

Change `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout` which have purple color and Height property of root `RelativeLayout` should be `match_parent`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrappingScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/longView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <View
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <View
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: nice answer  , +1

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same result :-( You can even try it yourself, just add Activity with this layout, and you can see for yourself, that on API18-19 this doesn't work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accepted solution, here is how to workaround the layout bug programatically:

```
        panelLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(final View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                if (bottom != oldBottom) {
                    v.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            v.getLayoutParams().height = mButtonsStripLeft.getHeight();
                            v.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

It allows to change the height of `longView` dynamically and still have the workaround work properly.

I was not able to make it work, with `animateLayoutChanges="true"` set on `panelLayout`. So it has to be disabled.